# Change list-style-image on slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Html

```
<ul class="main">
    <li class="item_no">Item 1
        <ul class="sub_items">
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
            <li>Item 1.2</li>
            <li>Item 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item_no">Item 2
        <ul class="sub_items">
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
            <li>Item 2.2</li>
            <li>Item 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item_no">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul.main {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul.main li.item_no {
    list-style-image:url('arrow.png');
}
ul.main ul.sub_items li {
    list-style-image:none;
}
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_items').hide().filter(':lt(1)').show();

    $("li.item_no").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub_items").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

When I click on "item_no", I want to change list-style-image from "arrow.png" to "arrowdown.png".

Does anyone know how to do it???

Comment: create one more class with `arrowdown` image and toggle it when you click `item_no`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub_items').hide().first().show();
    $(".main > li").click(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        self.toggleClass('item_no item_down');
        self.children('.sub_items').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Add this CSS:

```
ul.main li.item_down{
     list-style-image:url('arrowdown.png');
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shL9jopp/5/)**

Comment: Its not working for first "item_no". First "item_no" is not hidden, then also its showing "arrow.png" instead of "arrowdown.png".

Comment: @AmarPawar it seems working fine to me in your provided fiddle. Can you please explain what exactly not working in detail.

Comment: Sub_items of Item 1 are not hidden. So list-style-image of Item 1 should be "arrowdown.png".

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmkeseqc/)

```js
$("#ul_lst").hide();
$("#img_up").hide();
$("#arrow_up").hide();
$("#link1").click(function () {
 
$(".exclass").slideToggle(1000);
$("#arrow_up").toggle();
$("#arrow_dw").toggle();
$("#img_up").toggle();
$("#img_down").toggle();
 
});
```

```css
.demomenu {
width: 220px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin-bottom: 1em;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Verdana, Lucida, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #333;
}
.linkclass {
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 0.5em;
border-left: 5px solid #8AA1B6;
border-right: 5px solid #8AA1B6;
background-color: #6898d0;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
}
.exclass
{
width: 220px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: normal;
font-family: Verdana, Lucida, Geneva, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color: #e5eecc;
color: 000000; 
}
.lst_sty{
 list-style:none;
 }
.img_up
{
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/fpwRSGA.png');
  display:inline-block;  
}
.img_down
{
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/WmtRYL9.png');
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="exclass" id="ul_lst"><li class="lst_sty">This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example! </li>
<li class="lst_sty">This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example! </li>
<li class="lst_sty">This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example! </li>
<li class="lst_sty">This is sliding text example!</li></ul>
<div class="demomenu">
 <a class="linkclass" id="link1" href="#">Products </a><span class="arrow_up" id="arrow_up">></span><span class="arrow_dw" id="arrow_dw"><</span>
    <img class="img_up" id="img_up" height="24" width="24" >
<img class="img_down" id="img_down" height="24" width="24" > 
</div>
```